# Interpolating/Extrapolating values in 2D array to lines

Tags: python, interpolation, self-organizing-maps, extrapolation

I am trying to group things together, using a self organising map (SOM), and U-matrix that look like the following things:

**Fig 1: Self organising map (SOM) of light curves**
[image: Fig 1: Self organising map (SOM) of light curves]
**Fig 2: U-matrix for the above SOM**
[image: Fig 2: U-matrix for the above SOM]
**Fig 3: local maxima for above U-matrix**
[image: Fig 3: local maxima for above U-matrix]

Figure 3 is drawn using `plt.imshow`, and is made of a 2D array of values between 0 and 1 to define colour.

I want to interpolate and extrapolate the lines in Fig 3 to join up, allowing the graph to be separated into 6 regions. I am a bit stuck on how I might do this, and was wondering if anybody has any ideas?
I'm not necessarily looking for code, I would mostly like an idea of how to get started.

For anyone interested in the background of what I am doing here are some bits and pieces, but this is not necessary for my question.

- The things are [light curves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light_curve)
- [Stuff on what a SOM is and how it's made](http://www.ai-junkie.com/ann/som/som1.html)
- [What is a U-matrix, and how is it made](http://users.ics.aalto.fi/jhollmen/dippa/node24.html)

Comment: Thanks for the help in formatting I wasn't allowed to doe that because of low karma, don't suppose you could also add the tag u-matrix as I'm not allowed?